# How Do I format an 'if' conditional into a variable?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variables

I have a function where if a -Exception parameter is present, I need to use a different if statement. Is there a way I can put in if statement conditionals into a variable?

```
function Set-ErrorProvider
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control[]]$Controls,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$TextBoxException,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateSet("MiddleLeft")]
        [string]$Alignment,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$Message,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$Padding,
        [switch]$Clear
    )
    
    # Exceptions are written in the format of an if statement condition
    # e.g. -and $TextBox -ne "TextBoxAction"
    
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('$TextBoxException').Equals($false))
    {
        $TextboxIf = $Control.Text -eq $null -or $Control.Text.Trim().Length -eq 0
    }
    else
    {
        $TextboxIf = '$Control.Text -eq $null -or $Control.Text.Trim().Length -eq 0 $Exception'
    }
```

I'm having trouble formatting the $TextboxIf variable because I want to use it as below:

`if ($TextboxIf)`

The $Exception variable will hold something like "-and $Textbox.Text -ne $null" (a custom exception).

Any ideas on how to format the if conditional for the $TextBoxIf variable?

Comment: `Invoke-Expression ('$Control.Text -eq $null -or $Control.Text.Trim().Length -eq 0 {0}' -f $exception)` but I would rethink the code / logic you want to follow

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking I need to rethink it as well.

Comment: `$TextBoxException` should be a `[ScriptBlock]$TextBoxException` and than `... -and  &$TextBoxException`.

Comment: that would be a better approach likely @iRon // then the condition could become `-not $Control.Text -or -not $Control.Text.Trim().Length -and (& $exception)` - but this requires the `-and` to be outside the scriptblock

Comment: If I just wanted to return a $true or $false value which I think may be easier in this case, could create a scriptblock and get a return value?  I tried:

`$string = @"
if(`$DDPopup.Text -eq "No"){$true}
else {$false}
"@


`$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($string)`


I tried the above but had no luck...